# Mocking a class with Both Constructor and field injection

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, autowired

I have a class, where I added the dependencies as constructor injection as well as one as field injection

```
@service
public class MyService {


    private final ClientOne clientOne;
    private final ClientTwo clientTwo;

    @Autowired
    private SpecialClient specialClient;

     public MyService(ClientOne clientOne,
                        ClientTwo clientTwo){
        this.clientOne=clientOne;
        this.clientTwo=clientTwo;
     }
```

When I write test case, If I use `@InjectMock` on `MyService` ,  in case of mixed type of dependencies Mockito will use Constructor to create the Mock and my `SpecialClient` will be null.
`SpecialClient` an internal dependency so I do not have a setter for it and it is private too.

**Workaround**

For now I made `specialClient` package private in above class(*removed private before specialClient*)
Then explicitly setup the mock in target class after creating the object with constructor code is shown below.
But in reality this should be private, I can still use some ReflectionUtils to set the private field in setup method but that's also another Hack.

**Question is**
Is there a way Mockito provide a solution for such scenario. to initialize all dependencies ?

```
class MyServiceTest{
     
         MyService myService;
         
         @Mock
         ClientOne clientOne
         @Mock
         ClientTwo clientTwo
         @Mock
         SpecialClient specialClient
    
        @BeforeAll
        void setup(){
            myService = new MyService(clientOne,clientTwo);
            myService.specialClient=specialClient;
        }
    }
```

And No I can not add specialClient as Constructor Arg, Its actually a `requestScope` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use @InjectMocks to inject the dependencies both by constructor injection and by setter injection, which is clearly documented by @InjectMocks:

> Mockito will try to inject mocks only **either by constructor injection, setter injection, or property injection in order** and as described below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito won't report failure; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.
>
> 1. Constructor injection; the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. **If the object is successfully created with the constructor, then Mockito won't try the other strategies. Mockito has decided to no corrupt an object if it has a parametered constructor.**
>    Note: If arguments can not be found, then null is passed. If non-mockable types are wanted, then constructor injection won't happen. In these cases, you will have to satisfy dependencies yourself.

You need to turn to Spring-specific tools - let Spring create `MyService` bean and autowire it into your test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class})
public class MyServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    ClientOne clientOne;

    @MockBean
    ClientTwo clientTwo;

    @MockBean
    SpecialClient specialClient;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I DID mention in my question that I can not use injectMock.

Comment: Did you try to run the code you suggested ?   
When I convert all `@Mock` to `@MockBean` and use `@Autowired` on class `MyService` I get the error  `No qualifying bean of type '........MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}` ...
I did change the Extension to `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class})`